# Wanting to add a second React reducer with useReducer

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer

I currently have a single reducer that first checks for if SUCCESS or FAILURE is sent as an action.  Only once the `loading` state is false, do I want the other actions to be checked.  I realize the code below is not quite right, but just wanted to paste something to give an idea of what I'm trying to solve.

I'm feeling like somehow, all the code after `if (state.loading === false)` could be in another reducer but I can't figure out how to do that. I've tried several wrong ways and keep getting odd errors.

```
const dataLoadingReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FAILURE':
      return {...state,loading: true}
    case 'SUCCESS':
      return {...state, loading: false}
  }
  
  // only do the next set of dispatches if state.loading is true, otherwise ignore
  if (state.loading === false) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_YEAR':
        return {...state, year: 'xxx'}
      case 'SHOW_SESSIONS':
        return {...state, year: '111'}
      case 'HIDE_SESSIONS':
        return {...state, year: '222'}
      case 'SHOW_FAVORITES':
        return {...state, year: '333'}
  
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You should check the `state.loading` in your component and from there dispatch these actions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want separate reducers? If so use `combineReducers` (https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers).

However, when you dispatch an action, such as `SET_YEAR` you should expect that action to be handled consistently. No secondary, erroneous or conditional behaviour should occur in your reducers. This can cause a variety of issues. If that action should not occur because of the value of `loading` then that action should not be dispatched in the first place. Redux reducers are for state-management, not orchestration of business events/rules.

Comment: Is it not reasonable to want to guard against actions not meant for the reducer?  In a perfect world, no one would call them wrong, but my preference is to keep them from doing anything bad.

Comment: With the `switch` statements and the value of `action.type`, a reducer will not handle a specific action unless you have coded a `switch` case that handles the particular action type. 

If you are more so meaning that these are two different objects stored in, then have a look at my initial doc link provided. That describes that use case.

Comment: Thanks @Harley, I did look at that and it does not cover the "guard" case I'm worried about, just concatinates the actions together (assume I'm understanding it correctly).  More specifically, I'm trying to do something similar to what xstate does which is almost identical to useReducer with its useMachine hook. That does have actions that are only valid under certain state conditions.  (like you can't set a light bulb to on if it's state is also broken.

Comment: I believe redux reducers should only update state, not handle business logic. In your example, if the light bulb is broken, then you shouldn't send an action to turn it on to the redux store. You may find custom middleware may meet your needs. You can intercept actions prior to them arriving at reducers. Here, you can have some logic, perhaps to change the action/payload or trigger other actions subsequent actions.